# Change Implementation of Select, Update, and Insert in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

To give you the question first: I want to know if it is possible to create a stored procedure or something in SQL Server that intercepts and translates SELECT, INSERT, and UPDATE commands. Now for the explanation:

I am writing a web application to replace an old desktop app. Its a business app which is basically a database interface with reports and searches and all the good ol' CRUD. The new and old apps need to live in harmony together since some customers may be using the old and new together to access the same DB.

My problem is that the original database format stores most data in a single blob of text (1 nvarchar(MAX) field). I want to add functionality to search on fields stored in the blob, but it will be cumbersome and slow. I would like to update the database format without changing the desktop app at all, hence the question above.

It occurs to me that I could do this on the client by writing a wrapper class for the data access object and then do a bulk replace in the client code to reference the wrapper, but I want to know what my options are on the server as well.

In case anyone wants to know, the old app is in VB6 and the new in C#.

**EDIT**

Alright, so it looks like if I do anything on the server side we are looking at adding stored procedures and then updating the client VB6 code to reference the stored procs. Do something like a bulk replace of SELECT with sp_oldselect ... To return the data in a different format. I'm guessing a client-side wrapper would be the best solution for the time-being. Old apps die hard.

Comment: Wow this is not a good idea in so many ways

Comment: In addition to using a front end client, you could limit CRUD operations to stored procedures that perform the desired logic, rather than let users run adhoc CRUD queries.

Comment: I've added an answer, since the question is interesting, but it is too broad, it will get close votes in it's current state with the 'too broad' or 'primarily opinion-based'. Can you narrow down the problem to chunks with exact problems? Can you answer them? (if yes, don't ask it, if no, do some research, then if it is not help, ask it with the steps to reproduce the problem, the things what you found during you research, and the things what you have tried).

Comment: @Pred - Personally I think broader conceptual questions are a helpful part of the forum. In this particular case I asked the question because searching the internet yielded no answer as to whether having the server reinterpret simple select statements was possible. I often find many threads that are closed as "off-topic" and "opinion-related" to be helpful. Sometimes an uninformed programmer needs an answer or two to a vague question before they can  present a more well-formed query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a bunch of views for the old client and let it to query those views. It will be slow as hell in most cases, but it can 'replace' the select query. For updates and insert.. well.. instead of triggers on the views **could** help is some cases, but it will require lots of processing.

However my suggestion is to provide exactly the same functionality in the web app and deprecate the desktop app. When the desktop app's share is low enough, stop supporting it. From this point, you are (mostly) free to add new functions, upgrade the database schema, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with JonH, that alot can go wrong here, but you can try and read up on the `INSTEAD OF` Triggers in MS SQL server here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179288(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: There is no `SELECT` trigger.

Comment: No there is not :) And it will not solve all of his problems, but as fare as i know there is no way to change the way `SELECT` works.

Comment: This suggestion would have been better suited to a comment than an answer.

Comment: I will do that next time :)